# Loop through a set of files in one folder

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a requirement to loop through the particular files in a folder and merge those into one file and want it to achieve using a Batch file. My files look like below.

```
ILCY_NEW_20110908123008
ILCY_NEW_20110908123009
ILCY_NEW_20110908123010
```

meanining, `ILCY_NEW_timestamp`. The folder will have other files as well but I only need ones with today's timestamp. So I have written the following code to loop through all the files and combining the names into variable `CL`.

```
set tt=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%
for %%f in (ILCY_NEW_%tt%* . *) do set cl=%cl%+%%f 
set cl=%cl:~1%
echo %cl%
copy %cl% ILCY_NEW_CQ.csv
```

But, only the last file gets selected with this and it only gets copied into `ILCY_NEW_CQ.csv` ignoring all previous files, even though they have today's timestamp in the name. Can anyone help me here please?

Answer (score 1):

I can't get your date logic to work on my machine, but assuming that your for loop is correctly getting the right filenames, you can do something like this:

```
set tt=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%
for %%f in (ILCY_NEW_%tt%*.*) do type "%%f" >> ILCY_NEW_CQ.csv
```

The '>>' will append to the file (as opposed to '>', which would overwrite it). See [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/keyboard-ninja/keyboard-ninja-concatenate-multiple-text-files-in-windows/) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Copy command can handle wildcards by itself:

```
set tt=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%    
copy ILCY_NEW_%tt%*.* ILCY_NEW_CQ.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the time stamp for today automatically, use this little for loop with serg's copy command:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%A IN (`date /t`) DO (
 SET tt=%%C%%A%%B & copy /y "ILCY_NEW_%tt%*.*" "ILCY_NEW_CQ.csv"
)
```